# Puppet do wrong command for create user

Tags: debian, puppet, user-management

I have 2 debian boxes. One with puppetmaster, second with puppetd.

```
# puppet -V
2.7.18
```

In manifest i have:

```
group {
    "tipadima":
        ensure   => present,
}
user {
    "tipadima":
        shell => $operatingsystem ? {
            FreeBSD  => '/usr/local/bin/zsh',
            Debian => '/usr/bin/zsh',
        },
        comment  => 'tipadima',
        home     => '/home/tipadima',
        password => '$1$Iasdfsa33Pv$6vF/Pe.Xr.Nv0gGl.VNjx/',
        groups   => 'tipadima',
        require =>   Group["tipadima"] ,
        ensure   => present,
}
```

But this produce an error on client:

> info: Applying configuration version '1359531648' err:
>   /Stage[main]/Tipadima_files/User[tipadima]/ensure: change from absent
>   to present failed: Could not create user tipadima: Execution of
>   '/usr/sbin/useradd -s /usr/bin/zsh -d /home/tipadima -G tipadima -c
>   tipadima -p $1$sdgdf$6vF/Pe.Xr.Nv0gGl.VNjx/ tipadima' returned 9:
>   useradd: group tipadima exists - if you want to add this user to that
>   group, use -g.

Why, and how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use gid to specify the primary group, groups is for secondary membership

```
user {
    "tipadima":
        shell => $operatingsystem ? {
            FreeBSD  => '/usr/local/bin/zsh',
            Debian => '/usr/bin/zsh',
        },
        comment  => 'tipadima',
        home     => '/home/tipadima',
        password => '$1$Iasdfsa33Pv$6vF/Pe.Xr.Nv0gGl.VNjx/',
        gid      => 'tipadima',
        ensure   => present,
}
```